# CSS issue trying to create section with a background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

So in this page i have the login bar on the right and the footer ont eh bottom and i want a div that will sit in the area currently taken up by the background image and fill it with the full background image.

As of now everything is wrapped in a wrapper and the background image is hidden behind the login

```
    <section id="wrapper" class="login-register">

        <div class="login-box login-sidebar">
            <div class="white-box">
                <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform">
                    @{ Html.RenderPartial(SharedPartialViews.Logo.GetDescriptionAttribute()); }

                    @if (CurrentURL.Contains("Login"))
                    {
                        <div>
                            <h4 style="text-align:center;margin-bottom: -1px; margin-top:5px;">Investor Portal Login</h4>
                        </div>
                    }

                    @{ Html.RenderAction(nameof(SystemMessagesController.GetLoginSystemMessages), nameof(SystemMessagesController).GetControllerName()); }
                </form>

                @{ Html.RenderPartial(SharedPartialViews.CookieAlert.GetDescriptionAttribute()); }
                <div id="mainBody">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div id="backgroundImage" class="" style="position:relative;height:95%!important;width: 75%!important;">
              
          </div>
        <div class="login-footer">
            @{ Html.RenderPartial(FooterPartialViews.Index.GetDescriptionAttribute()); }
        </div>
    </section>
```

the background image div is the one im trying to place in that area.
So basically i want to have this div fit to the left of the nav bar and above the footer and be responsive.
I was able to just force a sized box into there with the image but the second the page resized the  image did not resize.

[image]

Here are some of the css that creates this.

[image]
[image]

ive tried a bunch fo things.
I just need a new div container that will fill that area between the login menu and hte footer.
And have that container contain the entire background image and not hide it behind the login menu.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the image of the final output ur looking forward and if you can add code as working snippet it will be eaier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is with `grid`.

Your section would be a grid with 2 columns and 2 rows.  The login footer spans both columns.  Set the height of the section to 100vh if you want it to be the size of the viewport.

```css
.login-register {
  display: grid;
  /* image col 2x form col */
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  /* footer row is only as tall as content */
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content; 
  /* height of viewport */
  height: 100vh;
}

.background-image {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/48/500/200);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 75% bottom;
}

.login-box {
  /* align form vertically in col */
  align-self: center; 
  /* align form horizontally in col */
  justify-self: center; 
  max-width: 20rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.login-footer {
  /* footer spans all columns */
  grid-column: 1 / -1; 
  border-top: 1px solid hsl(0 0% 80%);
  color: hsl(0 0% 60%);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  font-size: .85rem;
}

* {
  /* make sure to set box-sizing */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* just for demo purposes */

form {
  display: grid;
  padding: 1rem;
  gap: .5rem;
}

input {
  padding: .25rem;
  border: 1px solid hsl(0 0% 70%);
  width: 100%;
}

::placeholder {
  color: hsl(0 0% 70%);
}

button {
  padding: .5rem .75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: hsl(204 72% 30%);
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="login-register">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
  <div class="login-box login-sidebar">
    <div class="white-box">
      <form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="loginform">
        <div>
          <h4 style="text-align:center;margin-bottom: -1px; margin-top:5px;">Investor Portal Login</h4>
        </div>
        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <label for="pw" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pw" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      <div id="mainBody"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="login-footer">
    <span>privacy policy</span>
    <span>terms of use</span>
    <span>contact us</span>
  </div>
</section>
```